# One login in flutter app and website based on MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, flutter, dart, authentication

I have new flutter app with dart, and old website based on MySQL, there is tab in app that go to specific page in the website.

I want to connect my app database to website database to make user do one login, so when he login into the app, and press tap that make him go to the website, he is already logged in in the website, Is that possible?

Comment: You can use [http_package](https://pub.dev/packages/http) to make http requests into your API of the website and retrieve database information

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.